# Override save vs Custom field in Django

Tags: django, field, admin

I am writing code for a django app and I need a model field that comes from the value of other 2 of the same model.

I've created the field because I want to store it's value in de DB and not to leave it´s value just as coded logic in the views/admin. Until now I've stored all the values through a population script that called the model method before saving.

The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to create a solution that can be called from the population script (called as a cron activity daily) and the default django structure (mainly admin and views).

I want it to be able to be edited through the admin change form but indirectly (changing the other 2 values) while,if possible, displaying it.

Should I create a custom field or override the saving method?
Is it possible to avoid assigning a value to a field while creating it?
I could write a default and a `blank = true` but won't ensure me that the value is correct.

**Models.py**

```
class Valores(models.Model):
    TARIFAS = (
        ('1', '2.0A'),
        ('2', '2.0DHA'),
        ('3', '2.0DHS'),
        # (None, 'Elije una tarifa')
    )

    PERIODO_TAR = (
        ('1', 'Punta'),
        ('2', 'Valle'),
        ('3', 'Supervalle'),
        # (None, 'Elije una tarifa')
    )

    PERIODO_HOR = (
        ('1', '00-01'),
        ('2', '01-02'),
        ('3', '02-03'),
        ('4', '03-04'),
        ('5', '04-05'),
        ('6', '05-06'),
        ('7', '06-07'),
        ('8', '07-08'),
        ('9', '08-09'),
        ('10', '09-10'),
        ('11', '10-11'),
        ('12', '11-12'),
        ('13', '12-13'),
        ('14', '13-14'),
        ('15', '14-15'),
        ('16', '15-16'),
        ('17', '16-17'),
        ('18', '17-18'),
        ('19', '18-19'),
        ('20', '19-20'),
        ('21', '20-21'),
        ('22', '21-22'),
        ('23', '22-23'),
        ('24', '23-24'),  # (None, 'Elije un periodo horario')
    )

    per_hor = models.IntegerField(
        'periodo horario',
        choices=PERIODO_HOR
    )
    per_tar = models.IntegerField(
        'periodo tarifario',
        choices=PERIODO_TAR
    )
    tar = models.IntegerField(
        'tarifa',
        choices=TARIFAS
    )

    def periodo_tarifario(self):
        # Devuelve el periodo tarifario
        if self.tar == 1:
            return 1

        elif self.tar == 2:
            if 12 < self.per_hor < 23:
                return 1
            else:
                return 2

        elif self.tar == 3:
            if 1 < self.per_hor < 8:
                return 3
            elif 8 < self.per_hor < 14 or self.per_hor == 1 or self.per_hor == 24:
                return 2
            else:
                return 1
```

Comment: What is the reason why you do not want to leave it as coded logic? Maybe that can help us to understand more what you need.

Comment: I want to display it in the admin site but also through templates. Methods can be called in templates and in the model site of the admin but  fieldsets and list_filter in admin.py only support fields so I can´t display it on the chage form or filter by its value. Addiotionally I can to display "names" (like choices) in some places (admin for example) and use it´s value in other places (in some templates):

Answer (score 1):

How about using the following structure:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    A_Field=models.IntegerField()
    B_Field=models.IntegerField()
    C_Field=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)#this is the generated field

    def get_C(self):
        return self.A_Field+self.B_Field

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.C_Field=self.get_C()
        super(MyModel, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

Assigning an already correct default value (e.g. default = get_C in the field definition) will fail as A_Field and B_Field will not have a value at the point it is invoked.If you need this to be immediately evaluated as soon as you change A and B in a form you will need to use JS to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So the best way to generate a method based field is calling its method overriding the saving process. I will try it and discard the custom method way.